# Create marklogic db using xml in node js

Tags: xml, node.js, express, marklogic

I need to create marklogic do using XML (not json) from nodejs. I found marklogic nodejs api but there is just examples for using it with json not xml.
Can somebody tell me how to do it using XML?

Answer (score 2):

Is the question about creating XML documents or creating a REST server and database?

To create XML documents, you can supply the XML as a string as in the following test:

https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/master/test-basic/documents-core.js#L135-L141

You can also supply the XML as a ReadableStream open on an XML file.  The following test shows the basic technique.

https://github.com/marklogic/node-client-api/blob/master/test-basic/documents-core.js#L112-L118

For XML, the basic technique would be modified by using extensions and mime type would be for XML and by opening the stream with fs.createReadStream():

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

The Node.js API doesn't support the REST API request that creates a database, but you can use the standard Node.js HTTP or HTTPS request to invoke that endpoint:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest
- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/rest-apis

Hoping that helps,